# InstallShield 2012: With Dynamic FIle Linking is there a way to swap one file for another

Tags: installshield

I am using Dynamic File Linking to define the files I want my component to install.  I have a case where I need to install one version of a DLL when the client machine has version X installed and a different verion of the DLL when they have version Y installed.  I was hoping there was a setting (Condition) that could be used like there is is with SQL scripts. Can this be done or do I need to do something like have one feature for version X and another feature for version Y where the user can only choose 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's simply not possible for InstallShield to have this level of understanding of what your installer needs to do when "dynamically" picking up files.  I don't suggest using dynamic at all but if you must, you need to list your file name to "exclude" from the "dynamic" and then author those files as components directly in your installer.  Once you do that, you can take advantage of the condition property on the component.

The only other alternative would be to create additional dynamic components and associate them to features that have conditions to manipulate the Install Level of the feature and it's components.

Comment: I removed the dynamic link and used the component wizard to add all of the folders and files from my web app.  Upon attempt to build I now get "File not found.  An error occurred merging Module 'MDAC27ENU.C9C35FC7_5AEE_4C1E_8BD2_80ED9FA87FFF:1033' for Feature"  I saw a post you did on the Flexera Software Forum from 2008 saying one should be careful about adding that module.  I checked the Redistributable Downloader and MDAC27 does not show up in the list.  Why the change in build behavior from dynamic link?  Is this an IS thing or something to do with my client's app?

Comment: I might be getting picked up as a dependency. Check your components and make sure all the dependency scanning attributes say Properties Only and rebuild.  Another possibility is it's a module dependency of another merge module you have in your installer.

Comment: You probably also want to go into Tools | Options | .NET and select Properties only there for all newly created components.

Comment: That was it. I set the ".Net Scan at Build" value to be Properties Only for all of the components and the build was successful

Comment: InstallShield was "helping" you.  It detected a dependency on a DLL that's contained in a merge module.  Problem is  MDAC 2.7 has been built into Windows since XP. See the following page for all the information you could ever need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810805.aspx